# How can i add a new object to my json file in java instead of overwriting it?

Tags: java, json, file, gson

Im currently building a GSONFileWriter class.

```
public class GSONFileWriter {

private File jsonFile;

private final String json;

public GSONFileWriter(String json) {
    this.json = json;
}

public void generateJsonFileIfNotExists(String pathname) {
    try {
        jsonFile = new File(pathname);
        if (!jsonFile.exists()) {
            if (jsonFile.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File successful created.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Building the file went wrong!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        fillJsonFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: Building the file went wrong!");
    }
}

private void fillJsonFile() {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(jsonFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        writer.append(json);
        writer.println();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

it is called inside my CLI class

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(target);
            GSONFileWriter gsonFileWriter = new GSONFileWriter(json);
            gsonFileWriter.generateJsonFileIfNotExists("EmployeeData.json");
```

It creates and builds a new JSON File with an object inside it.

```
{"salary":34000.0,"name":"Hans","age":30,"id":"d40507a7-a802-4494-9a0c-5a97a0a4d0bf"}
```

However the Problem is, that whenever i run the code again, the old file gets overwritten and a new one created. I tried to change the code, so that it adds a new object to the file, instead of overwrite it. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:
At first: Read your json file as String if it exists.

```
 String file = "<File>";
 String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
```

Second you transform this string into a JsonObject using JsonParser:

```
JsonObject object = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

now you obtained your json-file as JsonObject tree and can manipulate this as you like. Using:

```
JsonObject.get(<MemberName>);
JsonObject.add(String <propertyName>, JsonElement <value>);
JsonObject.addProperty(String <propertyName>, Number/String/Boolean/Char <value>);
```

, etc.

Whenever you are finished you can write this to your json-file, either through a `OutputStream` or whatever you like.